# Grouping rows based on an intervals through a large data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with millions of rows, I want to add a column "group" that group the rows by groups of 1000 rows eg.

```
row  group
1    1
2    1
.    .
.    .
1000 1
1001 2
.    .
.    .
2000 2
.
.
```

I guess it is duplicated question but I couldn't find the right answer to my query.

Comment: `group = rep(1:round(nrow(data)/1000),each=1000,length.out = nrow(data))`

Comment: `c(0,1:nrow(data)%/%1000)[-(nrow(data)+1)]+1`